# Javascript padStart to populate an array doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I want to populate an array with different headings in Markdown format. It's what I tried:

```
slides = Array(50).fill().map((e,i)=> "Slide ".padStart(i % 6, '#') + (i+1));
```

But none of the array elements has a hashtag in the beginning. Debugger also shows that it doesn't have any effect on the string:

```
"Slide ".padStart(6, "#") = "Slide "
```

I expected from above:

```
"Slide ".padStart(6, "#") = "######Slide "
```

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I added to the question.

Comment: since `'Slide '` is 6 characters long, and you pad **to** 6 characters, and you use `i%6` which is at most `5` ... no padding will ever occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`padStart` pads to a *total* length. If you want to repeat a string and add it to the start, you can do that with `repeat`:

```
slides = Array(50).fill().map((e,i)=> "#".repeat(i % 6) + "Slide " + (i+1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the padding in front of the string.

```js
var slides = Array.from(
        { length: 50 },
        (_, i) => ''.padStart(i % 6 + 1, '#') + "Slide " + (i + 1)
    );

console.log(slides);
```